# What does "go by" mean?

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

> They will wait, well disposed, for others to remedy the evil, **that**
>   they may no longer have it to regret. At most, they give only a cheap
>   vote, and a feeble countenance and Godspeed, to the right, as it **goes
>   by** them.

1. What does "go by" mean here?
2. What is "that" refer to? They are well disposed that ...?
3. How to paraphrase this two sentences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example from [Henry David Thoreau's *On the Duty of Civil Disobedience*](http://www.literaturepage.com/read/civildisobedience-5.html)

He is being critical of the lack of action by the opposition to slavery, and that many will have nonaction until the problem

> **goes by** them

meaning "passes by and goes on possibly resolved by someone else".